# Grammatical error

Tags: error

> *The shopkeeper was pleased when we told him this kinds of mangoes were very delicious*.

The shopkeeper was pleased (a)
when we told him (b)
this kinds of mangoes (c)
were very delicious. (d)
No error (e)

Here I am not getting where is the error in this sentence.
Please help me.

Comment: "This Kinds" sounds odd !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like "homework" (and OP hasn't suggested anything he thinks *might* be wrong, or *why*).

Comment: I would bet any money this "test" was set by a non-native speaker, unaware that relatively speaking, [the intensifier ***very** is rarely used in conjunction with **delicious***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+very+tasty%2Care+very+delicious%2Care+tasty%2Care+delicious&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20very%20tasty%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20very%20delicious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20tasty%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20delicious%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Shaddy - You'll find the community might be more receptive to these kinds of questions if you tell us more about where you found this problem. (It seems to be from a practice test of some sort.) Also, tell us if can figure out any part of this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (b) **this** kinds of mangoes

is incorrect. *this* is singular, but *kinds* is plural. It should be:

> **these kinds** of mangoes

or

> **this kind** of mangoes

but in this case use "*was* very delicious"

Comment: True, but, in this case, the former would be correct (because the next part of the sentence reads: _**were**_ [plural] _very delicious_).

Comment: @J.R. I missed that. I edited my answer.